# How to split a dataframe column into multiple rows and transform string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, jupyter-notebook

I am pulling some data from a graphql api and the data I am getting is being returned in a dict like this:

[image: raw data return]

and then I also turned the dict into a pandas dataframe which returns this:

[image: pandas df]

so from my beginner understanding, it looks like the 'swaps' row is just a super long string. I was looking at some online tutorials and still cannot figure out how to transform this row into many rows (its 1000 rows). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: df_rows = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df['data']['swaps'])

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only convert value of `swaps` to dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(x['data']['swaps'])
```